# URL rewriting for WordPress Network (Multisite) subsite

Tags: networking, wordpress, rewrite, f5-big-ip

We have an install of WordPress Network (Multisite) that has multiple blogs running under the url blogs.exampleurl.com where each subsite is blogs.exampleurl.com/site1 /site2 etc...

We have a user that already has a URL (www.exampleurl.com/usersite/) and would like to keep his URL but also use our install of WordPress. Can this be done with an f5? If so, what would need to be done?

Comment: Can you be a tiny bit more specific about the rules you need?

Answer (score 0):

If the user is an internal one behind the same F5 Big-IP, then the direct answer to your question is yes. You can use an HTTP Class to match the URI in question and direct the back-end request the pool associated with your wordpress site. Your web server would need to be configured to accept this host alias and possibly rewrite the URL to process it properly.

If the user is a third-party user, you'd need to look into a frame or iframe. A less desirable alternative that would completely mask the fact that you're hosting this blog for them would be to have the user implement a reverse proxy. This would slow the site dramatically as well as decrease reliability in general.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with an iRule. In fact, the ProxyPass iRule (http://devcentral.f5.com/wiki/iRules.ProxyPassV10.ashx) would likely be the least effort approach.

If you wanted to go a little more spartan, it would be a matter of rewriting the host and uri information passed back to the wordpress servers for the HTTP Request, and undoing the modification in the HTTP Response. Unless you just want to write you own iRule, the ProxyPass one would suffice.